# How do I sort a JSON file name that has numeric file names as the key using Python?

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have a JSON file that has file names and a description for each as the key value pairs. However using OrderedDict when I try to sort the file it results in the order
0.jpg
1.jpg
10.jpg
11
.....
2
20
and so on.

```
op={int(k) : v for k, v in output.items()}
```

I tried doing this but it returns a ValueError. 
The error is as follows

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1520.png'**

Comment: you try to convert `str` to `int` in your case you do `int('1520.png')`

Comment: Seems like you want [Natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OrderedDict(sorted(output.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0].split('.')[0])))
```

---

### Example

```
output = {f'{i}.jpg': None for i in reversed(range(21))}

od = OrderedDict(sorted(output.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0].split('.')[0])))
```

#### Output:

```
OrderedDict([('0.jpg', None),
             ('1.jpg', None),
             ('2.jpg', None),
             ('3.jpg', None),
             ('4.jpg', None),
             ('5.jpg', None),
             ('6.jpg', None),
             ('7.jpg', None),
             ('8.jpg', None),
             ('9.jpg', None),
             ('10.jpg', None),
             ('11.jpg', None),
             ('12.jpg', None),
             ('13.jpg', None),
             ('14.jpg', None),
             ('15.jpg', None),
             ('16.jpg', None),
             ('17.jpg', None),
             ('18.jpg', None),
             ('19.jpg', None),
             ('20.jpg', None)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It worked. Could you please elaborate what you did in the second line?

Comment: which bit on the second line? it's all quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `int()` function on a string that's not entirely made up of digits. The dictionary comprehension you've built is going loops through each key/value pair in the original dict `output` and tries to cast each key to an integer.

In your example the keys are filenames like "0.png", "1.jpg", "10.png", etc. and a string like `'10.png'` can't be turned in to an integer. That's why you're getting the `ValueError`.

Ordering dictionaries in Python is a little tricky because we think everything should be based on a key's value when in fact Python orders dictionary keys based on their hash value.

As for using an OrderedDict, that container only remembers the order in which the keys were inserted. It sounds like it would give you some sorting capability, but it can only guarantee that the order in which you loop through keys is the same as the order you put them in the dictionary.

This should help you out though:

```
od = OrderedDict()
for key in sorted(output):
    od[key] = output[key]
```

This will put all the keys of the original dict `output` in a list, sort it, and then stick each one in sorted order in the OrderedDict with the correct value.